# PyCharm (Version 5) does not start under Ubuntu 15.10 since last Java Update

Tags: pycharm

When trying to start PyCharm over the terminal (it does not start over the icon at all) I get the following errors:

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have tried the solution suggested here but all I got was a window from PyCharm telling me about a bunch of Java errors. https://askubuntu.com/questions/624199/problem-with-java-while-trying-to-run-pycharm-community-4-5

I think the last update was something about Java. My current Java version is 9-ea:

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+109-2016-03-09-204305.javare.4620.nc)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+109-2016-03-09-204305.javare.4620.nc, mixed mode)

Comment: So perhaps Java 9 explicitly removed the now-deprecated PermGen flags in one of its builds?  Besides, why are you using Java 9 anyway? That's not stable.

Comment: I honestly don't know... I have change it to version 8 now, and PyCharm is back to normal. Thank you!

Comment: Sure.  Next time, don't put "solved" in your title, and if you've answered your question, feel encouraged to post an actual *answer* to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>This is copied verbatim from the original question.  Moving it to an answer for its appropriate exposure.</sup>

I changed the Java version to 8 and the problem was solved!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am still new to this community and have seen people add SOLVED to the title after they edited their question with the appropriate answer. I will keep it in mind :)!